# image.link help me undertand the code please

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink

I have following javascript code

```
if(this.images[index]) {
    var context = this;
    var image = this.images[index];
    var img_container = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('ad-image');
    var img = $(new Image()).attr('src', image.image);
    if(image.link) {
      var link = $('<a href="'+ image.link +'" target="_blank"></a>');
      link.append(img);
      img_container.append(link);
    } else {
      img_container.append(img);
    }
```

it has if(image.link) condition, I want to get this so that it satisfies this condition but I don`t know what it is checking for by image.link. 
what should I have to make image.link return true?

Answer (score 0):

Any value which is not evaluated as `false`. In this particular case I think a non-empty string is expected.
See [`converting to boolean`](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/) to better understand rules.